# SDL Web 8 Uncaught reference error $om is not defined when creating new Structure Group with Metadata Keywords

Tags: web8

[image]I try to create a new Structure with Metadata Keywords. Metadata values not load in the dropdown and got error

> Uncaught reference error $om is not defined.

Any please suggest to me.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide some error details, if the error is thrown in the CME? In case the error came from the browser console, it sounds like you might be having some connection problems, but maybe a screenshot of the CME could show a bit more of what is happening.

Comment: It`s sdl web 8 code  issue. fixed issue in the KeywordField.js(\tridion\web\WebUI\Core\Controls\FieldBuilder\FieldTypes\KeywordField.js)

Comment: var value = node.getAttribute("xlink:href") || $dom.getInnerText(node);

Comment: I strongly doubt that assumption that it is a SDL Web code issue - there's people running this software in live environments, surely they created Structure Groups before...

Comment: Quickly testing this I was able to save a SG even with a metadata keyword field value. However I do see this $om in the KeywordField.js of my SDL Web 8.1 setup. I would recommend opening a support ticket for this to explain exactly the steps to reproduce so that other users could benefit from a fix if this happens to be a defect happening under certain circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the info. already open the sdl support ticket for this issue and SDL Web8 R & D team also agree the code mistake.

Comment: Weird that it works then :) thanks for opening a ticket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks SDL fixing this issue in sdlweb8.5:

```
tridion\web\WebUI\Core\Controls\FieldBuilde‌​r\FieldTypes\Keyword‌​Field.js

var value = node.getAttribute("xlink:href") || $dom.getInnerText(node);
```